# Verify Toast messages

Tags: android, python, selenium, appium

I am trying to find out how to check a toaster message.
I am not a developer and I am very new to automated testing.
I use python, so is there any possibility to have python code in detail that allows to check a toaster message on an android device.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In general, there is no difference b/w toast message and any other UI element in your app to search and manipulate:

```py
 self.driver.find_element_by_id("your_app_package/your_app_toast_id")
```

However, I had several times a problem that toast is appearing & disappearing way too fast for Appium to catch: it is invisible in Android Accessibility layer, so you can't get page source and check it there.

Luckily, with new Espresso Driver you can invoke your test app internals (including toasts) and check it. This is way more reliable but takes time to [set up](https://appiumpro.com/editions/64).

Answer (score 0):

1. The relevant [XPath Expression](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727) would be something like:

   ```
   //android.widget.Toast
   ```
2. Due to [Toast](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts) nature it is not always available/visible so you will have to [wait until it appears](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

Suggested code:

```
toast_text = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//android.widget.Toast"))).get_attribute("text")
print(toast_text)
#do whatever you need with the "toast_text" string
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello try below code for Toast message.
In case you have more than one toast then pls. change the index number.

```
toastMsg = wait.until(lambda x:x.find_element_by_xpath("//android.widget.Toast[1]"))
print(toastMsg.get_attribute("name"))
```